# Get Facebook Permission to Post / Like / Comment on friends wall/posts

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk

What i did not tried, every permission, nothing works.

My app is almost ready, but i can't get myself to figure it out.

How do i post like or comment on friends wall or his posts through the app.

Both of the users are approved in the app, how do i make them reply / like each others posts ? what permission do i need(read_stream, publish_stream not exists anymore)

Thank you.

BTW, if it does matter, i'm using LARAVEL + https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk

Answer (score 0):

**"Publish_action"** will work for post status on behalf of user. publish_stream is replaced by publish_action.

Refer : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-publish_actions

Comment: It wasnt my question at all.

Comment: For posting this is the permission and this is part of the answer. I hope so.